# Illustrate Trapzeium/ Simpson rules using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have several functions plotted and now need to illustrate the error between the actual area/ integration and the approximate area/ integration result (calculated using either the trapezium or simpsons rule). Got this far from researching here/ other places and it only draws one triangle at the moment - in an incorrect position I think. Any input? Thank you in advance.

N.B.The exact value and also approximate integral values have been calculated earlier in the program if those are required.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1(x):
    return np.exp(-4*x)*np.cos(6*np.pi*x)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1500)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(322)
xstep = np.arange(0,2)
ax1.fill_between(f1(xstep), 0, xstep, facecolor='white')  # Trapezium
ax1.plot(x, f1(x),'r-')  # Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the triangle is in the wrong spot.

The problem is with [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) - the arguments should be `(x1, y1, y2)`, where `y1` is the value that determines where "between" is. If you up the number of triangles in your code, you'll see what's happening - the x and y axes are swapped. If you change that the triangle points will be at the correct values.

Here's the code I used to check with. Note that I added a variable n_steps (made it easier to test):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1(x):
    return np.exp(-4*x)*np.cos(6*np.pi*x)

# parameters for trapezoid rule
n_steps = 6

# set up figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)#(322)

# range for function
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1500)
xstep = np.linspace(0, 1, n_steps)

# plot the trapezoid
ax1.fill_between(xstep, 0, f1(xstep), facecolor='white')

# plot the function
ax1.plot(x, f1(x),'r-')  # Function

plt.show()
```

The result looks like:

[image: graph result]

The black line at y=0 is made by `fill_between`. I would recommend placing vertical lines at the points, to make it more clear how the calculation is done. You would add the code for that after plotting the trapezoid, but before plotting the function:

```
# plot vertical lines
for xval in xstep:
    ax1.plot((xval, xval), (0, f1(xval)), color='black')
```

which results in:

[image: graph with vertical lines]